# Telegram removes public links to the channel

Tags: telegram

I created a public telegram channel and created a public link for it. All was well for six months.

This morning I found out that the public link is not working. When I try to enter the channel using the link, it shows me that the name was not found.

In the settings, I noticed that my channel type has become private. I was surprised. I tried to change the channel type to public and there was no problem, I changed the channel type to public. Then there was the following problem - I could not return the previous name of the channel to him. When you try to give it the same name that was, it shows an error that the link is not correct. I had to name the channel by a different name.

My previous channel name is not taken and when I try to give it this name, it shows that the name is not correct.

I don't know what's going on. What could it be? I have not found a similar situation anywhere.

Comment: This question is not programming related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same here. I found only one piece of information on the issue https://teleuz.info/telegram-removed-usernames/

It seems that Telegram carried out a cybersquatter massacre somewhere around August 20 2022 and the usernames are just blocked now. Hope they will become available for use later.